# Calling method from other class

Tags: oop, pyqt5

I'm very new to PyQt5, and I'm trying to make an interactive gui for plotting of data. However, this problem may well be completely unrelated to PyQt5 and more a problem with my understanding of object oriented programming in general.

I have a `MainWindow` class, a `SupportClass1` and a `SupportClass2`. When I make an instance of `SupportClass1`, I want to call the method `DoSomething` in the `MainWindow` class by referring to the object `window`, but I get the error message `NameError: name 'window' is not defined`.

I have no problems creating a method in the `SupportClass2` and calling that from the `MainWindow` class so I get the impression that I have not instantiated the `MainWindow` class correctly which I don't understand as I thought I had defined `window` as an instace of the `MainWindow` class.

Can anyone help me understand what is wrong in my logic and how to solve this problem?

````
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
import os
from random import randint


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()

        self.x = list(range(100))
        self.y = [randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)]

        self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')

        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0))
        self.data_line =  self.graphWidget.plot(self.x, self.y, pen=pen)

        self.button = QPushButton('Test')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.InstantiateSupportClasses)

        self.gui_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.gui_box.addWidget(self.graphWidget)
        self.gui_box.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(self.gui_box)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test application')
        self.show()

    def InstantiateSupportClasses(self):
        supp_class2 = SupportClass2()
        print(supp_class2.GetVariable())

        supp_class1 = SupportClass1()

    def DoSomething(self):
        print('I did something!')


class SupportClass1():
    def __init__(self):
        window.DoSomething

class SupportClass2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_variable = 5

    def GetVariable(self):
        return self.some_variable


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()```
````

Answer (score 0):

I see that you are using the "window" object from the "SupportClass1" class.
but that class does not recognize this object one solution is to insert that object to the "SupportClass1()"

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtCore
from pyqtgraph import PlotWidget, plot
import pyqtgraph as pg
import sys
import os
from random import randint


class MainWindow(QWidget):

    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

        self.graphWidget = pg.PlotWidget()

        self.x = list(range(100))
        self.y = [randint(0,100) for _ in range(100)]

        self.graphWidget.setBackground('w')

        pen = pg.mkPen(color=(255, 0, 0))
        self.data_line =  self.graphWidget.plot(self.x, self.y, pen=pen)

        self.button = QPushButton('Test')
        self.button.clicked.connect(self.InstantiateSupportClasses)

        self.gui_box = QVBoxLayout()
        self.gui_box.addWidget(self.graphWidget)
        self.gui_box.addWidget(self.button)

        self.setLayout(self.gui_box)

        self.setGeometry(300, 300, 300, 150)
        self.setWindowTitle('Test application')
        self.show()

    def InstantiateSupportClasses(self):
        supp_class2 = SupportClass2()
        print(supp_class2.GetVariable())

        supp_class1 = SupportClass1(self)

    def DoSomething(self):
        print('I did something!')


class SupportClass1():
    def __init__(self, window):
        window.DoSomething()

class SupportClass2():
    def __init__(self):
        self.some_variable = 5

    def GetVariable(self):
        return self.some_variable


def main():
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    app.setStyle('Fusion')
    window = MainWindow()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thanks that works. But do you know why the instace "window" cannot be called without this workaround?

Comment: A bit philosophical, that's how Python works.
If you are in a class, it does not recognize objects outside the class unless you have entered them or you have set them to be global